# Decipher the greeting card $( X^2 +Y^2 -1 ) ^3 - X^2 Y^3 = 0$

Tags: problem-solving

A friend of mine just got a rather weird congratulations card through the door

[image: Greeting card image]

They have zero idea what it means, I have tried graphing it and nothing spectacular comes out. Is there a standard name for this equation or does it signify anything?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your question and title do not match

Comment: Why don't you try plotting it in Wolfram Alpha? :)

Comment: I got curious about the XXX at the end :-D

Comment: Either the card is very weird or your personal situation is quite weird. Is it really true you have a significant other who shares a birthday with you and you have an anniversary on the same day?!! :) Or maybe it is just a card-for-all-occasions...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using Maple it is:

```
 [> with(plots):
    implicitplot((x^2+y^2-1)^3-x^2*y^3 = 0, x = -10 .. 10, y = -10 .. 10);
```

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

[image]

Comment: I love how bad the first couple of plots look.

Comment: Awesome progression! +1

Answer (score 9):

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeartCurve.html

Have a look at the second graph here

It is a cardiod curve.

Comment: lol ! lucky guy !!

Answer (score 8):

Your friend had a great equation for his greetings, check the graph below

[image]